# Twisted sending files. python

Tags: python, networking, twisted

I'm trying to transfer images and other files over the network using Twisted. I use for this the class "FileSender" and in particular the method "beginFileTransfer", which I use on the server. But the file is not fully received by the client and I can't open it. At the same time, if I send a small file it comes. So the problem is the size. Can you tell me how I can send big files? Below is the server and client code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, connectionDone
from twisted.python import failure
from twisted.protocols.basic import FileSender
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet import reactor


class TestServer(Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        filesender = FileSender()
        f = open('00000.jpg', 'rb')
        filesender.beginFileTransfer(f, self.transport)


    def dataReceived(self, data: bytes):
        data = data.decode('UTF-8')
        print(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason: failure.Failure = connectionDone):
        print("Server lost Connection")

class QOTDFactory(Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return TestServer()

# 8007 is the port you want to run under. Choose something >1024
endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8007, interface="127.0.0.1")
endpoint.listen(QOTDFactory())
reactor.run()
```

---

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ClientFactory, connectionDone
from sys import stdout
from twisted.protocols.basic import FileSender

from twisted.python import failure


class TestClient(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        print("Client did connection")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        f = open('13.jpg', 'wb')
        f.write(data)
        self.transport.write("Client take connection".encode('UTF-8'))

    def connectionLost(self, reason: failure.Failure = connectionDone):
        print("Client lost Connection Protocol")

class EchoClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        print('Started to connect.')

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print('Connected.')
        return TestClient()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print('Lost connection factory.  Reason:', reason)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print('Connection failed factory. Reason:', reason)

from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 8007, EchoClientFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Twisted uses non-blocking socket operations: data written to or read from sockets are just enough to not block. Filesender in effect sends chunks of data until all are sent and you need to buffer them until they are complete.

I would write the server part as:

```
class TestServer(Protocol):
    
    def connectionMade(self):
        filesender = FileSender()
        f = open('00000.jpg', 'rb')
        d = filesender.beginFileTransfer(f, self.transport)
        d.addCallback(lambda _: self.transport.loseConnection()) # signals end of transmission
```

Then the client as:

```
class TestClient(Protocol):

    def __init__(self):
        self.f = open('13.jpg', 'wb')

    def connectionMade(self):
        print("Client did connection")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.f.write(data) # I would buffer all the received data and
                           # write them all at once for efficiencey
                           # but this one will do

    def connectionLost(self, reason: failure.Failure = connectionDone):
        self.f.close() # server is done sending all chunks, close the file
        print("Client lost Connection Protocol")
```

HTH